# VBA: Detecting value in cell with dropdown list

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

I am having some trouble detecting the value in a cell with a dropdown list.

When I am running the below code, it only gives me the value 0 in column `I`. Column `H` contains a number of `Dropdown lists` (made by data validation), which value can either be Yes or No:

```
Sub DropDownlistValue()

Dim Holidays As Worksheet

Dim Checkbox_RowCount As Long
Dim HolidayCount As Long

Set Holidays = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Visning")

Checkbox_RowCount = Holidays.Cells(Holidays.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

For HolidayCount = 2 To Checkbox_RowCount
    If Not IsEmpty(Holidays.Range("H" & HolidayCount)) Then

        Holidays.Activate
        Holidays.Range("H" & HolidayCount).Select

        If ActiveCell = "YES" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = 1
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = 0
        End If
    End If
Next HolidayCount

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question has been solved by below answer. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you possibly need is the change in this line:

```
If ActiveCell = "YES" Then
```

into

```
If Ucase(ActiveCell) = "YES" Then
```

One more tip- move this line:

```
Holidays.Activate
```

before/outside your loop.

Comment: There's no need for `select` and `activate` when looping through the rows and checking for non-empty cells. Why don't you change your code to encourage using `Holidays.Range("H" & HolidayCount).offset()` instead of `active cell`?